# Change innerWidth and innerHeight to custom size THREEjs

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

When I launch the code below it automatically calculate the height and width. Is there any way I can set the window where the function launches in to a custom size?

I tried changing this part of the code but no luck so far:

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

Here is the code of the function.

```
//////////////settings/////////

var movementSpeed = 30;
var totalObjects = 500;
var objectSize = 70;
var sizeRandomness = 0;
var color = 0x00BEE0;


/////////////////////////////////
var dirs = [];
var parts = [];
//var container = document.createElement('div');
//document.body.appendChild( container );
var container = document.getElementById('header');
//document.body.appendChild( header );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
camera.position.z = 1000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function ExplodeAnimation(x, y) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    for (i = 0; i < totalObjects; i++) {
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.x = x;
        vertex.y = y;
        vertex.z = 0;

        geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
        dirs.push({
            x: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
            y: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
            z: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2)
        });
    }
    var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
        size: objectSize,
        color: color
    });
    var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, material);

    this.object = particles;
    this.status = true;

    this.xDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
    this.yDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
    this.zDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);

    scene.add(this.object);

    this.update = function() {
        if (this.status == true) {
            var pCount = totalObjects;
            while (pCount--) {
                var particle = this.object.geometry.vertices[pCount]
                particle.y += dirs[pCount].y;
                particle.x += dirs[pCount].x;
                particle.z += dirs[pCount].z;
            }
            this.object.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
        }
    }

}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();




function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    var pCount = parts.length;
    while (pCount--) {
        parts[pCount].update();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', onclick, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onClick() {
    event.preventDefault();
    parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation((Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2), (Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2)));
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

document.getElementById("btn-header-trigger").addEventListener('click',run);

function run() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation(0, 0));
    render();
}
```

Comment: do you want to set the annimation container to custom size , or resize the window it self ??

Comment: @bRIMOs example https://youtu.be/ViwI_2bQ40A . you see how the animation pushes the menubar down? I want the function to run within the dark blue area without pushing the menubar down. I hope the example can help you!

Comment: So you want let it with fixed height ? as the start height ?

Comment: @bRIMOs yes with a fixed width and height. So it won't push the menubar down. the width of the header is 100% and height is 91vh. I want the function to run within the same measures.

Comment: see my below answer

Comment: @bRIMOs this works! Thanks matey!

Comment: you're welocme , dont forget to accept the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to either calculate or set initial value of height in a var like :

```
//canvasHeight =  document.getElementById('header').clientHeight if height already set with css 
var canvasHeight = 250;
```

then in both the resize window function an the builtin render function you replace the `window.innerHeight` by  the `canvasHeight`, as below :

```
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / canvasHeight;
  ...
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, canvasHeight);
}
```

and inside the run function

```
function run() {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, canvasHeight);
  ...
}
```

You can try the below snnipet :

```js
//////////////settings/////////

var movementSpeed = 30;
var totalObjects = 500;
var objectSize = 70;
var sizeRandomness = 0;
var color = 0x00BEE0;

//here you set or you calculate it 
//canvasHeight =  document.getElementById('header').clientHeight
var canvasHeight = 250;

/////////////////////////////////
var dirs = [];
var parts = [];
//var container = document.createElement('div');
//document.body.appendChild( container );
var container = document.getElementById('header');
console.log(container);
//document.body.appendChild( header );

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
camera.position.z = 1000;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function ExplodeAnimation(x, y) {
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  for (i = 0; i < totalObjects; i++) {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = x;
    vertex.y = y;
    vertex.z = 0;

    geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
    dirs.push({
      x: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      y: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2),
      z: (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2)
    });
  }
  var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial({
    size: objectSize,
    color: color
  });
  var particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, material);

  this.object = particles;
  this.status = true;

  this.xDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.yDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);
  this.zDir = (Math.random() * movementSpeed) - (movementSpeed / 2);

  scene.add(this.object);

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.status == true) {
      var pCount = totalObjects;
      while (pCount--) {
        var particle = this.object.geometry.vertices[pCount]
        particle.y += dirs[pCount].y;
        particle.x += dirs[pCount].x;
        particle.z += dirs[pCount].z;
      }
      this.object.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
  }

}

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();




function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  var pCount = parts.length;
  while (pCount--) {
    parts[pCount].update();
  }

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}

window.addEventListener('mousedown', onclick, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

function onClick() {
  event.preventDefault();
  parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation((Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2), (Math.random() * sizeRandomness) - (sizeRandomness / 2)));
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / canvasHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, canvasHeight);
}

document.getElementById("btn-header-trigger").addEventListener('click', run);

function run() {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, canvasHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  parts.push(new ExplodeAnimation(0, 0));
  render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-header-trigger">Click to run </button>
<div id="header"></div>
```